# MacVim is unable to find Fira Code when launched from Tmux

Tags: tmux, macvim

I have `set guifont=Fira\ Code:h14` on my `.vimrc` and it works perfectly on Macvim. However, if it is launched from within `Tmux`, it won't load the font and throw an error saying `invalid font(s)`.

I installed the font using `brew-cask` but I doubt this is the problem as it works when launching outside `Tmux`, maybe some config is missing. How can I solve this?

Comment: Does it work when you launch vim from a terminal, but *not* within Tmux? Like directly in `iTerm2`? When you say "outside Tmux", it's not clear whether you only mean from within MacVim, or also from another terminal.

Comment: If I open Macvim double-clicking, it works. If I type `mvim` in iTerm2, it works. However, if I open `tmux`, and then, from within tmux, I type `mvim`, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Run `:set guifont=*`, which should bring up a GUI font selector on Mac. Notice which fonts are present and missing when you launch it inside and outside of Tmux.  Check where the found vs not-found fonts are located on the filesystem. Is there a pattern?

This sounds like a different PATH or environment is being set inside and outside of Tmux that makes a difference. You could also capture the output of `env` inside and outside of `tmux` to compare differences in environment variables.

Comment: If this counts as a pattern, the not-found font is located in `~/Library/Fonts`. It is only 1 font (Fira Code), but to be fair that's the only font I have installed so far. The tmux PATH include all the paths (and more) than when I run `!env` on Macvim launched double-clicking.  None of this paths says anything about the fonts directory